# Getting Cloudfree image for small area (Sentinel-2) using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, cloud-cover

I am trying to get a cloudfree image from Sentinel-2 for multiple small areas (circles with a radius of 20km) in Ghana, a very cloudy area. Using the standard algorithms (median image, filter for least cloudy image etc.) for an area of interest did not work. The problem is that these algorithms always filter the entire picture instead of only focussing of the cloud cover of the small area I'm actually interested in. As a result the small areas often have clouds (when filtering for cloud cover) and the median images look cloudy/foggy as well.

Is there a way to receive the least cloudy image, where cloudiness is only calculated / taken into account for a small area of interest?

I tried solving it as follows, but the code seems to fail:

```
// filter image by geometry (geometry is a small polygon at the coast of Ghana)
// the image is supposed to 1st be clipped to the area of interest, 
// followed by only choosing images with little cloudiness:

var SENTINEL = ee.ImageCollection ('COPERNICUS/S2')
.filterDate('2020-01-01', '2022-02-28')
.map(function(image){return image.clip(geometry)})
.filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 'less_than',20);


// choose median and visualize resulting image
var SENTINELMED = SENTINEL.median();
var sent_med_color = SENTINELMED.select( ['B4','B3','B2']);

var trueColorSen = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 2000.0,
};

Map.addLayer(sent_med_color,trueColorSen , 'Sentinel');
```

Comment: You have basically two approaches to do this. Mask clouds with some cloud coverage product like: SCL band, CLOUD_PROBABILITY, QA60, etc. or by creating a function that calculates the proportion of clouds in a given AOI.

Answer (score 0):

There is an image collection with [cloud probabilities](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/COPERNICUS_S2_CLOUD_PROBABILITY), that you can use to mask out clouds:

```
var geometry = Map.getBounds(true)
var cloudThreshold = 30
var startDate = '2020-01-01'
var endDate = '2022-02-28'

var filter = ee.Filter.and(
  ee.Filter.bounds(geometry),
  ee.Filter.date(startDate, endDate)
)
var collection = ee.ImageCollection(
    ee.Join.saveFirst('cloudProbability').apply({
        primary: ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2').filter(filter),
        secondary: ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_CLOUD_PROBABILITY').filter(filter),
        condition: ee.Filter.equals({leftField: 'system:index', rightField: 'system:index'})
    })
).map(function (image) {
  var cloudFree = ee.Image(image.get('cloudProbability')).lt(cloudThreshold)
  return image.updateMask(cloudFree)
})

var median = collection.median()
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/1344864360a4af0080b222383e5df895

Answer (score 0):

The first step you should consider is to mask cloudy pixels. Don't just filter the image collection according to a percentage of clouds in the entire scene. To mask the cloudy pixels you can use several methods: Scene Classification (SCL) band if L2A processing level is available in your study area, QA60 available at L1C processing level, or the most recommended CLOUD_PROBABILITY (it is a collection of cloud probability images created with the [s2cloudless](https://docs.sentinel-hub.com/api/latest/user-guides/cloud-masks/) algorithm) Here the collection: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials/community/sentinel-2-s2cloudless. Here is an example using Python API:

First, you need a function do add de `cloud_probability` band to the Sentinel-2 image collection.

```
def S2_AddCloudProb(ImgCol_S2):
    
    '''
    
    Adds a cloud probability band to each image in a Sentinel-2 ImageCollection.
    The cloud probability information is obtained (pasted) from the COPERNICUS/S2_CLOUD_PROBABILITY product

    Args:
        ImgCol_S2 (ee.ImageCollection): Sentinel-2 image collection filtered (ej:COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED 
        filtered/selected)
    
    Assumptions:
        Both ImagesCollections should be limited spacial and temporaly before applying the function

    Returns:
        ImageCollection with a new band called 'cloud_probability' the probability (0-100 %)
    that a pixel is a cloud
  
    '''
    
    ImgCol_S2 = ee.ImageCollection(ImgCol_S2)

    # Get start date. When using .filterDate, this date is inclusive
    start_date = ImgCol_S2.sort('system:time_start', True).first().date().format('YYYY-MM-dd')

    # Get end date. When using .filterDate, this date is exclusive so, it is necessary to add a day
    end_date = ImgCol_S2.sort('system:time_start', False).first().date().advance(1, 'day').format('YYYY-MM-dd')

    ImgCol_CP = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_CLOUD_PROBABILITY').filterDate(start_date, end_date)

    join_filter = ee.Filter.equals(leftField='system:index', rightField='system:index')
    ColJoined = ee.Join.saveFirst('cloud_probability').apply(
        primary=ImgCol_S2,
        secondary=ImgCol_CP,
        condition=join_filter
    )

    def add_cloud_prob(image):
        image = ee.Image(image)
        properties = image.toDictionary().remove(['cloud_probability'])

        cloud_prob_image = ee.Image(image.get('cloud_probability')).select('probability').rename('cloud_probability')

        return image.addBands(cloud_prob_image).multiply(1).set(properties)

    ColwithCP = ColJoined.map(add_cloud_prob)

    return ColwithCP
```

Then, you can mask the clouds with this function:

```
def CloudMaskCP(threshold=None):
    
    '''
    Mask clouds in images of an image collection whose images have a band named 'cloud_probability' like the 
    one generated by S2_AddCloudProb. This function must be mapped over an ee.ImageCollection.
    
    Implicit argument: an ee.ImageCollection.
    
    Args:
        threshold (ee.Number): Probability threshold, in percentage [0-100], 
        to mask a pixel as a cloud. Pixels with cloud_probability greater than or equal to the 
        treshold will be masked.
    
    Assumptions:
        The image contains the 'cloud_probability' property inherited from the join between 
        the Sentinel-2 ImageCollection and the S2_CLOUD_PROBABILITY ImageCollection. The 
        cloud probability property has a band named 'probability' containing the probability
        (%) that a pixel is a cloud.
    
    Returns:
        Same image collection with cloud masked images.
    '''
    
    if threshold == None:
        threshold = 50
    
    def mask(image):
        image = ee.Image(image)
        isNotCloud = image.select('cloud_probability').lt(ee.Number(threshold))
        return image.updateMask(isNotCloud)
    
    return mask
```