# Error in random forest classification for the GEDI datasets in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, classification, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, random-forest

I am a beginner in GEE. I am trying to do the random forest classification for the GEDI datasets (rh13 and rh99) in Google Earth Engine. I want to do the classification of each point of the GEDI datasets and then interpolate for all the images (because the GEDI datasets are data points).

I'm getting this error  and do not how to fix it:

> Classified: Layer error: Property 'Relative Height' of feature '0_0'
> is missing

```
var Paracou = 
/* color: #d63000 */
/* displayProperties: [
  {
    "type": "rectangle"
  }
] */
ee.Geometry.Polygon(
    [[[-52.992228448173776, 5.3639624330339855],
      [-52.992228448173776, 5.216962579558439],
      [-52.898158013603464, 5.216962579558439],
      [-52.898158013603464, 5.3639624330339855]]], null, false);
var qualityMask = function(im) {
  return im.updateMask(im.select('quality_flag').eq(1))
      .updateMask(im.select('degrade_flag').eq(0));
};
var img = ee.ImageCollection('LARSE/GEDI/GEDI02_A_002_MONTHLY')
                  .filterBounds(Paracou)
                  .map(qualityMask)
                  .select('rh13','rh99')
                  .median();
var gediVis = {
  min: 1,
  max: 60,
};

var img = img.clip(Paracou);
Map.centerObject(Paracou,12);
Map.addLayer(img, gediVis, 'rh13-99');
print(img.getInfo());

var points = img.sample({
  'region': Paracou,
  'scale' : 30,
  'numPixels' : 200000,
  'seed' : 0,
  'geometries': true
});
Map.addLayer(points,{},'training',true);
print(points.size().getInfo());
print(points.first().getInfo());
//SPLIT AND TRAINING
// Use these bands for prediction
var bands = ['rh13','rh99'];

var label = 'Relative Height';

var sample = img.select(bands).sampleRegions({
    collection: points,
    properties : [label],
    scale : 30
  });
var sample = sample.randomColumn();
var split = 0.7;
var training = sample.filter(ee.Filter.lt('random',split));
var validation = sample.filter(ee.Filter.gte('random',split));
print(training.first().getInfo());
print(validation.first().getInfo());
var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(10).train(training,label,bands);
// Classification
var result = img.select(bands).classify(classifier);
Map.addLayer(result.randomVisualizer(),{},'classified');
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/37d6104d659f4dc63f36baccde372a16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't follow how you want this to work. What are the classes you want in your classification? Nevertheless, the reason for your error is this:

```
var label = 'Relative Height'
var sample = img.select(bands).sampleRegions({
  collection: points,
  properties: [label],
  scale: 30
})
```

The `points` collection doesn't contain any `Relative Height` property. Even if it did, I don't think this quite makes sense.

You could maybe try something like the below. Note that I've never used the GEDI data, and have very limited knowledge of it. So take this approach with a grain of salt. I'd very much appreciate someone with more knowledge on this to jump in and comment.

I'm extracting reference data from the GEDI collection, create Landsat 8/Sentinel 1 composites for the corresponding month, and sample it for training data. A classifier is trained, then finally applied to a composite for a date range of your choosing.

```
var aoi = ee.Geometry.Polygon([[
  [-52.992228448173776, 5.3639624330339855],
  [-52.992228448173776, 5.216962579558439],
  [-52.898158013603464, 5.216962579558439],
  [-52.898158013603464, 5.3639624330339855]
]]).buffer(1e4)

var heightBand = 'rh95'

var gedi = ee.ImageCollection('LARSE/GEDI/GEDI02_A_002_MONTHLY')
  .filterBounds(aoi)
  .map(function (image) {
    return image
      .updateMask(image.select('quality_flag').eq(1))
      .updateMask(image.select('degrade_flag').eq(0))
      .select(heightBand)
  })
var referenceData = gedi
  .map(toReferenceData)  
  .filterMetadata('count', 'not_equals', 0)
var trainingData = referenceData
  .map(toTrainingData)
  .flatten()

var composite = toComposite('2021-01-01', '2022-01-01')
var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(25)
  .train(trainingData, heightBand, composite.bandNames())
  .setOutputMode('REGRESSION')
var classification = composite.classify(classifier)


print('trainingData', trainingData)
print('classifier', classifier.explain())
Map.addLayer(referenceData.flatten(), null, 'reference data', false)
Map.addLayer(gedi.mosaic().clip(aoi), {bands: heightBand, min: 0, max: 40, palette: '#fffdcd, #e1cd73, #aaac20, #5f920c, #187328, #144b2a, #172313'}, heightBand)
Map.addLayer(composite, {bands: 'red,green,blue', min: 0, max: 2000, gamma: 1.6}, 'optical')
Map.addLayer(composite, {bands: 'VV,VH,ratio_VV_VH', min: [-20, -25, 3], max: [0, -5, 14]}, 'sar')
Map.addLayer(classification, {min: 0, max: 40, palette: '#fffdcd, #e1cd73, #aaac20, #5f920c, #187328, #144b2a, #172313'}, 'height')
Map.centerObject(aoi, 12)


function toReferenceData(gedi) {
  var referenceData = gedi
    .sample({
      region: aoi,
      scale : 25,
      numPixels : 200000,
      geometries: true
    })
    .map(function (feature) {
      // Can only use ints as classes
      return feature.set('rh99', feature.getNumber('rh99').round())
    })
  return referenceData
    .set({
      year: gedi.getNumber('year'),
      month: gedi.getNumber('month'),
      count: referenceData.size()
    })
}


function toTrainingData(referenceData) {
  var year = referenceData.getNumber('year')
  var month = referenceData.getNumber('month')
  var fromDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(year, month, 1)
  var toDate = fromDate.advance(1, 'month')
  var composite = toComposite(fromDate, toDate)
  return composite.sampleRegions({
    collection: referenceData,
    properties : [heightBand],
    scale : 30
  })  
}


function toComposite(fromDate, toDate) {
  return toOpticalComposite(fromDate, toDate)
    .addBands(toSarComposite(fromDate, toDate))
}

function toSarComposite(fromDate, toDate) {  
  var composite = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD_FLOAT')
    .filter(ee.Filter.and(
      ee.Filter.bounds(aoi),
      ee.Filter.date(fromDate, toDate),
      ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'),
      ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VV'),
      ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VH')
    ))
    .map(function (image) {
      return maskBorder(
        toDb(
          toGamma0(image)
        )
      ).select(['VV', 'VH'])
    })
    .median()
  return composite
    .addBands(
      composite.select('VV').divide(composite.select('VH')).rename('ratio_VV_VH')
    )
    

  function toGamma0(image) {
    var gamma0 = image.expression('i/(cos(angle * pi / 180))', {
      'i': image.select(['VV', 'VH']),
      'angle': image.select('angle'),
      'pi': Math.PI
    })
    return image.addBands(gamma0, null, true)    
  }
  
  function toDb(image) {
    return image.addBands(
      image.select(['VV', 'VH']).log10().multiply(10), null, true
    )    
  }
    
  function maskBorder(image) {
    var angle = image.select('angle')
    return image
      .updateMask(
        angle.gt(31).and(angle.lt(45))
      )    
  }    
}


function toOpticalComposite(fromDate, toDate) {
  return ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2')
    .filterDate(fromDate, toDate)
    .filterBounds(aoi)
    .map(function (image) {
      var qa = image.select('QA_PIXEL')
      var cloudShadow = bitwiseExtract(qa, 4)
      var snow = bitwiseExtract(qa, 5).rename('snow')
      var cloud = bitwiseExtract(qa, 6).not().rename('cloud')
      return image
        .updateMask(
          cloudShadow.not()
            .and(snow.not())
            .and(cloud.not())
        )
        .select(
          ['SR_B2', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B4', 'SR_B5', 'SR_B6', 'SR_B7'],
          ['blue', 'green', 'red', 'nir', 'swir1', 'swir2']
        )
        .multiply(2.75e-05)
        .add(-0.2)
        .multiply(10000)
        .int16()
    })
    .median()
}

function bitwiseExtract(value, fromBit, toBit) {
  if (toBit === undefined)
    toBit = fromBit
  var maskSize = ee.Number(1).add(toBit).subtract(fromBit)
  var mask = ee.Number(1).leftShift(maskSize).subtract(1)
  return value.rightShift(fromBit).bitwiseAnd(mask)
}
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/52f8f4ee6d2ab759e4f0fd1acb1ea2a9

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I actually want to classify the height at each point of the datasets (the value of rh99 for example). Which way should I follow?

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for this great work. I really need a tutorial for doing that.

Comment: Just as an experiment, I updated the answer to include Sentinel 1 in the composites.

Comment: Yess, Thank you. So for the Outofbag error, It's reduced a bit

Comment: If you include some band ratios in the optical composite, it might also improve the classification.

Comment: If I only use the sar composite, how could I improve the classification?

Comment: Perhaps by doing a so called time-scan. Include information like min/max/stdDev of imagery within a date-range. It requires some thinking though. You probably don't want to do this with these monthly date ranges. Try to always generate a composite for the whole year, and ignore the month.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I'll put more datasets (sentinel-2, ALOS) to compare which one is better with this classification.

Comment: https://code.earthengine.google.com/90c5594cf6589db0ea89f577be90da47. I have an error when adding the Sen2 composite. Could you help me to fix it

Comment: Look at this answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/426248/154371

Comment: I am following your guide and have already done it. Thank you

Comment: How could I separate the training data and validation data to do the assessment?